# Pre Populate Text Fields in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to fill out various text fields on an apex application when I select a Reference Number in a select list.

When the page loads I'd like the text fields to be filled with the information from the database related to the reference number from the select list, however, I don't know how to do so. Any suggestions or help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood the question:

- user opens a page
- there's a Select List item
- user picks a value
- you want to populate certain items on that page, based on a value user previously selected

If that's so, you'd use a **dynamic action** - create it on the Select List item, pick **set value** type.

**[EDIT: How to do that?]**

Scott's schema, `DEPT` table. Suppose that the select list item is `P15_DEPTNO`, while two other items are `P15_LOC` and `P15_DNAME`.

- create a dynamic action on `P15_DEPTNO`

  - event: change
  - item: `P15_DEPTNO`
- create its True action:

  - action: set value
  - type: SQL statement

    ```
    select loc, dname
    from dept
    where deptno = :P15_DEPTNO
    ```
  - items to submit: `P15_DEPTNO`
  - affected elements: items `P15_LOC`, `P15_DNAME`

That's all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That is what I wanted yeah. How would I structure the SQL statement to fill all the texts fields?

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my message and added steps which show how to do that. Have a look.